# Is there an alternative, faster approach than idxmax?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import time
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'gr': np.random.choice(7000, 500000),
              'col': np.random.choice(1000, 500000)})
groups = df.groupby('gr')
t1 = time.time()
idx = groups.col.idxmax()
print(round(time.time() - t1,1))
0.7
```

Is there a way to get these indeces significantly faster than with idxmax()?

Note, I am interested in the `idx.values`, I don't mind losing the `idx.index()` of the `idx` `series`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my side using `drop_duplicates` is faster than `groupby` `idxmax`, around 8 times faster

```
%timeit df.sort_values(['gr','col']).drop_duplicates('gr',keep='last').index
10 loops, best of 3: 67.3 ms per loop
%timeit df.groupby('gr').col.idxmax()
1 loop, best of 3: 491 ms per loop
```

Comment: @jezrael yes you are right , it is dup man :-) , thank you for find it out , also learn from the accepted answer

Comment: thank you for your answer. Indeed your approach is faster because my example has many smaller groups. However, your solution does not return the same result as my code. Could you please check?

Comment: @jezrael want me to remove it ?

Comment: @jezrael I tried , after I converted the com viki , he accepted it , i can not remove it now ...

Comment: In order to get the correct results, you need to respect the stability of the sort.  With a stable sort, the order will not be changed for those things with the same sorting value.  This gets messed up if you sort ascending then take last.  So instead, you want to sort descending **and** use a stable sorting algorithm like `mergesort`.  Use `df.sort_values(['gr', 'col'], ascending=False, kind='mergesort').drop_duplicates('gr').index`

Answer (score 3):

## Numba just in time compiling

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def idxmax_(bins, k, weights):
    out = np.zeros(k, np.int64)
    trk = np.zeros(k)
    for i, w in enumerate(weights - (weights.min() - 1)):
        b = bins[i]
        if w > trk[b]:
            trk[b] = w
            out[b] = i
    return np.sort(out)

def idxmax(df):
    f, u = pd.factorize(df.gr)
    return idxmax_(f, len(u), df.col.values)

idxmax(df)

array([   156,    220,    258, ..., 499945, 499967, 499982])
```

Make sure to prime the function in order to compile it

```
idxmax(df.head())
```

Then time it

```
%timeit idxmax(df)
%timeit df.sort_values(['gr', 'col'], ascending=False).drop_duplicates('gr').index

6.07 ms ± 15.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
152 ms ± 498 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

### Comparing equality

```
idx0 = df.groupby('gr').col.idxmax().sort_values().values
idx1 = idxmax(df)
idx2 = df.sort_values(
    ['gr', 'col'],
    ascending=False
).drop_duplicates('gr').index.sort_values().values

print((idx0 == idx1).all(), (idx0 == idx2).all(), sep='\n')

True
True
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. A couple points. For some reason `idxmax()` does not return the same result as `groups.col.idxmax()`. Further, the `drop_duplicates` approach you are timing also does not return the same result as the `idxmax()`. It needs `ascending=True` in `sort_values`, and `keep='last'` in `drop_duplicates`. Finally, even the 2 approaches you are timing do not seem to return the same results at least in my version (`python 3.5.0`, `pandas '0.18.1'`

Comment: You may have not sorted.  I've updated my post verifying equality.

Comment: Oh I see, ok you are 100% right. But if I might ask, why would one need to sort by index number? Wouldn't it make more sense to have the indices sorted by group id (`gr`), which is how the result is returned without  the `.sort_values()` bit in the `idxmax()`? Would it be too difficult for me to adapt your solution accordingly? Thanks very much

Comment: You can adapt my solution by returning `out` instead of `np.sort(out)`.